# Sorting a Google Query with Select and Where

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

This is my google sheet query:

```
=QUERY('Form responses 1'!A:AG,"select C,E,D+F,AF,I+J+K+O,M where toDate(B)= date '"&text(today()-1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' ",1)
```

How do I sort the above by column `C`? I have tried both `SORT BY` and `ORDER BY` but it comes up with `#Value`!

Also, I would like to have the result of `D+F-AF` in a column. Again it comes up with `#Value`!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've put some code formatting in, and got rid of some text that's not part of the question.  If you could link to the original sheet, that'd make our lives easier in finding the problem too.

Comment: Does the query work without any sorting?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you query looks fine apart from one thing.

Instead of `where toDate(B)`, try using just `where B`.

We can't see your spreadsheet so it's hard to tell if that's exactly the problem, but it looks like it to me.

I've set up a similar spreadsheet to test, and this works just fine:

```
=QUERY('Form Responses 1'!A:D,"select A,B,C,D WHERE B = date '"&text(today()-1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' ORDER BY B",1)
```